# Tread depth for tire replacement

Tags: tires

My tire tread depth is 6/32 according the the dealer service that I had today.. The car has 8000 miles. Do I need to think about replacing my tires?

Answer (score 1):

In most places, 2/32" is the legal minimum tread depth.  At 6/32" you are well above that and should be good to go.

Comment: A new tire has 10/32 or 11/32. At 6, you are only half worn. But if you have are going to wear out tires after 16,000 miles, either you drive hard or you have poor quality tires. 30,000 or 40,000 miles would be more typical for good quality tires. Like most things, you get what you pay for.

Comment: I find the quality of tyres doesn't affect their life but the performance, especially in the wet. Quite often, a tyre with better grip will wear out sooner, because the rubber is softer.

Comment: @alephzero - this may be a country thing, but I completely disagree with your numbers. I always replace tires around 10000 miles. On my old Subaru it was a little under that. On my current Kia it's a bit over. And I use Bridgestone Potenzas and similar. Tires with less grip will last longer, but that's a false economy from a safety perspective.